# Аргументы функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Как сделать так, чтобы функция принимала в качестве аргумента неограниченное количество аргументов (под звездочкой), но если аргумент пустой, то по умолчанию вызывать аргумент как ввод? Важно, чтобы это было сделано не условиями в самой функции. То есть: def a(*b = input()), но такой синтаксис не работает.

Comment: старайтесь более информативные заголовки использовать [ask]

Answer (score 4):

Через декоратор:

```
def decorator(func):
    def temp(*args):
        if not args:
            args = (input(),)
        return func(*args)
    return temp
```

Использование:

```
@decorator
def function(*args):
    print(args)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# если без использования декораторов

def function(*args):
    print(args)

args = []
function(*(args or [input()]))

none = lambda a: a or [input()]
function(*none(args))
```